# How to do i display custom attribute on order details page in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9

i want to change the 'Ship to Name' attribute to a custom attribute like 'employee id' from the customer account information page.
I want this change to be reflected in Order details page under 'sales tab' in magento.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: We will need to see what you have tried so far.  Please read up on how to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)